# Double Elimination Bracket Naming Convention

Tags: terminology, tournaments

So I've been working on creating a tournament bracket, and have drawn up some diagrams for how it will be run. The tournament involves 16 players. The Winners bracket is currently labelled like so: (with a few missing on the end)

[image: Winners bracket]

However, I wasn't sure how the naming convention worked for the Loser's bracket, as there are two rounds of the same size:

[image: Losers bracket]

How should these rounds be named?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few decent options for this bracket layout.  For a simplistic approach, you could simply label them *First Round, Second Round, Third Round... Final* and leave it at that.  Not very elegant, but serves the purpose of providing a label.

Another option could be to base the loser's bracket labels on the round from the winner's bracket they are coming from.

> *Qualifiers Elimination Round*
>
> *Eights Elimination Round*
>
> *Loser's Quarters Round*
>
> *Quarters Elimination Round*
>
> *Loser's Semi-Final Round*
>
> *Semi-Final Elimination Round*
>
> *Grand Final Elimination Round*

Alternatively, you could shuffle these around and use the term *Play-in*.

> *Qualifiers Elimination Round*
>
> *Eights Play-in Round*
>
> *Eights Elimination Round*
>
> *Quarters Play-in Round*
>
> *Quarters Elimination Round*
>
> *Semi-Final Elimination Round*
>
> *Grand Final Elimination Round*

I still see an issue with the "Grand Final" round, as the winner may have already beaten the loser and to win, the loser will have to beat the winner twice, but that's not really relevant to the question at hand, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I'll play around with them and see what I can come up with :)

Answer (score 1):

A system where contestants that do not advance due to failing to meet the qualifying standard (beating a set time or score, or in this case winning the match) is called *repechage*.

What you are aiming to create is called a *full repechage bracket* ("full" because all losing contestants have a chance to eventually return to the main competition in some way).

Therefore, the names of each round in each bracket can be numbered according to traditional systems, preceded by clarification of whether they are the Main or Repechage bracket.

In likely order of play, these rounds would be

1. Main Round 1
2. Repechage Round 1
3. Main Round 2
4. Repechage Round 2
5. Main Quartfinals
6. Repechage Quarterfinals
7. Main Semifinals
8. Repechage Semifinals
9. Repechage Final
10. Grand Final